# Sidekiq latency increasing rapidly and got memory exceeded issue on heroku

Tags: heroku, sidekiq

I have added active job with sidekiq, latency increasing rapidly so background job not doing calculation fast.What should i do to resolve latency problem along with memory exceed on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the concurrency or/and can increase worker dynos in heroku.